# How can i prevent post back in mvc http request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to prevent the request post backing which is need to be restricted in request start in mvc application

Answer (score -3):

you cant restrict the post back , you can use !Ispostback to prevent.

Comment: The `Page.IsPostBack` property is available for webforms only. MVC has special mechanism to prevent postback to a `HttpPost` method.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you please share that mechanism i am also facing the same issue.